# Ebean error - model is not enhanced?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, ebean

Spigot is apparently removing Ebean support in 1.12, so I'm switching to manual Ebean. I've been able to fix most of the errors myself, but this one is beyond me. I've tried all the different maven enhancement plugins and such, but none of them seem to fix it at all.

Error: https://gyazo.com/50cf77c853ceb492e5389394d37c6088

Code:

```
    MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
    dataSource.setUser(getConfig().getString("database.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(getConfig().getString("database.password"));
    dataSource.setServerName(getConfig().getString("database.url"));
    dataSource.setDatabaseName("minecraft");
    ServerConfig config = new ServerConfig();
    config.setDataSource(dataSource);
    config.setDefaultServer(true);
    config.setRegister(true);
    config.setClasses(getDatabaseClasses());
    if (getConfig().getBoolean("database.rebuild")) {
        config.setDdlGenerate(true);
    }
    config.setDdlRun(true);
    EbeanServerFactory.create(config);
```

FilterData:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "erudition_filters")
public class FilterData extends Model {

@Id
private long id;

@NotNull
private String world;

private double x, y, z;

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(double x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(double y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public double getZ() {
    return z;
}

public void setZ(double z) {
    this.z = z;
}

public void setLocation(Location location) {
    setWorld(location.getWorld().getName());
    setX(location.getX());
    setY(location.getY());
    setZ(location.getZ());
}

public Location getLocation() {
    return new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(getWorld()), getX(), getY(), getZ());
}

@Lob
@NotNull
private String itemsString;

public Inventory getItems() {
    try {
        if (getItemsString() == null)
            return null;
        return getItemsString().equals("none") ? null : ItemSerializer.fromBase64(getItemsString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public void setItems(Inventory items) {
    setItemsString(items == null ? "none" : ItemSerializer.toBase64(items));
}

public static FilterData createFilterData(Block block) {
    FilterData data = new FilterData();
    data.setLocation(block.getLocation());
    data.setItems(null);
    saveFilter(data);
    return data;
}

public String getItemsString() {
    return itemsString;
}

public void setItemsString(String itemsString) {
    this.itemsString = itemsString;
}

public String getWorld() {
    return world;
}

public void setWorld(String world) {
    this.world = world;
}

public static List<FilterData> getAllFilters() {
    return Ebean.getDefaultServer().find(FilterData.class).findList();
}

public static FilterData getFilter(Location location) {
    FilterData data;

    if (location.getBlock().hasMetadata("filterid")) {
        data = Ebean.getDefaultServer().find(FilterData.class,
                location.getBlock().getMetadata("filterid").get(0).asInt());
        if (data != null) {
            data.setLocation(location);
            return data;
        }
    }
    List<FilterData> filterDataList = Ebean.getDefaultServer().find(FilterData.class).where()
            .eq("world", location.getWorld().getName()).eq("x", location.getBlockX()).eq("y", location.getBlockY())
            .eq("z", location.getBlockZ()).findList();
    if (filterDataList.isEmpty())
        return null;
    if (filterDataList.size() > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < filterDataList.size(); i++) {
            if (filterDataList.get(i) == null)
                continue;
            deleteFilter(filterDataList.get(i));
        }
    }
    return filterDataList.get(0);
}

public static void saveFilter(FilterData data) {
    Ebean.getDefaultServer().save(data);
}

public static void updateFilter(FilterData data) {
    deleteFilter(Ebean.getDefaultServer().find(FilterData.class, data.getId()));
    Ebean.getDefaultServer().insert(data);
}

public static void deleteFilter(FilterData data) {
    Ebean.getDefaultServer().delete(data);
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public boolean supports(ItemStack item) {
    if (getItems() == null)
        return false;
    for (ItemStack supportedItem : getItems()) {
        if (supportedItem == null)
            continue;
        if (supportedItem.getType() == item.getType() && (supportedItem.getData().equals(item.getData())))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

Comment: Apparently, Eclipse's plugin works fine, but I need Maven for shade. A hacky way would be to just decompile the one Eclipse generates. Should I just do that?

Comment: > I've tried all the different maven enhancement plugins and such ... What exactly have you used? You are not showing any maven pom plugin ... which is what you'd need to do.  Are you using the maven plugin or tile ?  Which version?  When you set the debug level higher ... do you see the beans enhanced etc etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used Gradle instead of Maven, and I easily got it working. (Literally just added plugins {
  id "com.github.kt3k.ebean.enhance" version "3.0.0"
}
at the beginning and it worked with Gradle)

Comment: `  - In plugin 'com.github.kt3k.ebean.enhance' type 'org.kt3k.ebean.enhance.EnhanceEbeanTask' property 'antTaskName' is missing an input or output annotation.
`